# D3 -- Arcs for chord diagram not being displayed

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, chord-diagram

I trying to understand how the D3 chord diagram works.  My first step is to display the arcs for the diagram with following script.  But for some reason, the arcs are not showing up.

See web page [HERE](http://tobagoborn.com/test/cordExam4.html)

Can some one tell me what I am missing?

```
    <body>
    <script>
        // Chart dimensions.
        var width = 960, 
                height = 750, 
                innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .41, 
                outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1; 

  //Create SVG element with chart dementions
        var svg = d3. select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width) 
                .attr("height", height) 
                .append ("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate (" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"); 

//------------Reformat Data ------------------------------------------

        var matrix = [];  // <- here is the data 
        d3.tsv('picData.tsv', function(err, data) 
        {
            //console.log(data);
            pictures = d3.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
            //console.log(pictures);

            data.forEach(function(row) 
            {
                var mrow = [];
                pictures.forEach(function(c) 
                {
                    mrow.push(Number(row[c]));
                });
                matrix.push(mrow);
            //console.log(mrow);
            }); 
            //console.log('1st row: ' + matrix[0]);
            //console.log(matrix);
        });

//---------------- Define diagram layout ----------------------------

        var chord = d3.layout.chord() //<-- produce a chord diagram from a matrix of input data
                .matrix(matrix)  //<-- data in matrix form
                .padding(0.05) 
                .sortSubgroups(d3.descending);

        var fill = d3.scale.category20(); //<-- https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/API-Reference#d3scale-scales
            //console.log(fill);

        var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
                .data(chord.groups)
                .enter().append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "group"); 

                //console.log(g);

        // create arcs
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                .outerRadius(outerRadius);

                //console.log(arc);

        g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) {  console.log(d.index); return fill(d.index);})
            .style("stroke", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
            .attr("id", function(d, i) { return"group-" + d.index });;

        g.append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", 6)
                .attr("class", "picture")
                .attr("dy", 15)
            .append("svg:textPath")
                .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#group-" + d.index; })
                .text(function(d) { return pictures[d.index]; }); 
            //console.log(g);

    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that `d3.tsv` [is asynchronous](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv):

> > Issues an HTTP GET request for the comma-separated values (CSV) file at the specified url... The request is processed asynchronously.

As a result, all of your code under "Define diagram layout" is being executed *before any data is loaded*. Otherwise, your code works fine (See image below). So just move all your code into your `d3.tsv(...)` call and you'll be all set.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your script is running without errors, but no elements are being created from your data join.  That's usually a sign that you are passing in a zero-length data array.

In fact, you're not passing in an array at all; you're passing a function object.  When d3 looks up the array length of that object, it returns undefined, which gets coerced to the number zero, and so no groups and no chords are created.

Relevant part of your code:

```
    var g = svg.selectAll("g.group")
            .data(chord.groups)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "group");
```

To actually get the array of chord group data objects, you need to call [`chord.groups()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Chord-Layout#groups).  Without the `()` at the end, `chord.groups` is just the name of the function as an object.

---

Edited to add:

Ooops, I hadn't even noticed that your drawing code wasn't included inside your `d3.tsv` callback function.  Fix that, as described in [mdml's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26848626/3128209), then fix the above.

Comment: FYI you can just pass the function `chord.groups`, since `selection.data` can take in a function. See the second sentence of [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data). (MBostock also used basically the same code as the OP in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006).)

Comment: Ah, that's right.  The `chord.groups` function will get passed an undefined data object as a parameter, but that's okay since the function doesn't use parameters anyway.